# Use JS or jQuery to replace part of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Ok, I am not sure what is wrong with me, but I am trying to find and replace a portion of multiple URLs.

Basically, I have some URLs that are being dynamically added to my site. All have a class of 'newsLink' some of the links are pulling up google.docs viewer and I need to remove that.

Here is my code thus far:

```
$('a.newsLink').each(function(){
var lnk = $('a.newsLink').attr();
var re = new RegExp("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=","g");
lnk.replace(re, "");
});
```

the links look like:

```
<a href='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=myHomePage.pdf' class='newsLink' target='_blank'>
```

I would like to remove the first part so that the link looks like:

```
<a href='http://myHomePage.pdf' class='newsLink' target='_blank'>
```

Anyway, no luck this far...can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are getting all links again inside of the loop. Then, you try to get an attribute, but didn't say which one. Finally, you try to use `replace` without assigning the return value to anything.

This is what your code should be:

```
$('a.newsLink').each(function(){
    var lnk = this.href;
    this.href = lnk.replace("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=", "");
});
```

Note: I'm assuming you want the links to become e.g. `myHomePage.pdf`, without the protocol.

Comment: Okay, I dumped the regex entirely, after all it's not necessary. [Now it works](http://jsfiddle.net/bneLJ/1/).

Comment: Cool.  Even better than mine now.

Comment: Swiftly solution bro, since the URL is always a literal string (no alternation or iteration in the part which needs to be replaced), regex is unneeded. +1

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you want is.

```
http:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/viewer\?url=(.+)
```

First off, this escapes all regular expression characters.  In this case `\`, `.`, and `?`.  We are capturing the document using a group that matches every character (`(.+)`).

So our code looks like this so far.

```
$('a.newsLink').each(function(){
    var lnk = this.href;
    var re = /http:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/viewer\?url=(.+)/g
    this.href = lnk.replace(re, "");
});
```

Now we get the groups like so.

```
var match = re.exec(lnk);
```

This returns an array of the matches.  Our document is now stored in `match[1]`.  So our final code comes out to.

```
$('a.newsLink').each(function(){
    var lnk = this.href;
    var re = /http:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/viewer\?url=(.+)/g
    this.href = (re.exec(lnk))[1];
});
```